# If any question has the answer no, how to print a certain text

Tags: python

I'm stuck with a problem that asks 5 questions. If any of them has the answer no It should print ALIEN! or else Cool.
This is what I have got so far:

```
human = input("Are you human? ")
human = input("Are you living on planet Earth? ")
human = input("Do you live on land? ")
human = input("Have you eaten in the last year? ")
human = input("Is 2 + 2 = 4? ")
if human == "yes":
    print("Cool")
elif human == "no":
    print("ALIEN!")`
```

Comment: Do you want to print `Cool`/`ALIEN!` _after_ having asked the five questions or as soon as you get an answer that is `no` (and then stop the questions)? And what happens if you get neither `yes` nor `no`?

Comment: Your condition is getting evaluated based on the last response. i.e. `input("Is 2 + 2 = 4? ")`

Comment: jdehesa it is after all 5 questions have been asked then even if 1 has been answered with no then it should print ALIEN! otherwise Cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `any()` to check if any of the answers to questions is `'no'` and print message accordingly:

```
human = [input("Are you human? "), input("Are you living on planet Earth? "), 
         input("Do you live on land? "), input("Have you eaten in the last year? "), input("Is 2 + 2 = 4? ")]

if any(x.lower() == 'no' for x in human):
    print('ALIEN!')
else:
    print('Cool')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the variable human that is changed every time and given a new value using `input()` Try and make multiple variables instead of just using human.

```
human = input("Are you human? ")
var1 = input("Are you living on planet Earth? ")
var2 = input("Do you live on land? ")
var3 = input("Have you eaten in the last year? ")
var4 = input("Is 2 + 2 = 4? ")
if(human == "yes"):
    print("Cool")
elif(human == "no"):
    print("ALIEN!")
```

Comment: What if I enter `yes` for first question and `no` for rest

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't even work. The one above does.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: @Chirag it wont change because it is requesting the value of human and not the other variables

Comment: I have change the code so that python version 3.7 will work with it.

Comment: You don't need paranthesis in Python 3.7 or any version for that matter. Also, please read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about storing the variables and only care if one of the questions comes up as "no" or "n":

```
x=["human?","on earth?", "on land?","someone who eats food?","sure that 2+2=4?"]

for i in x:
    if input("Are you {}".format(i)).lower() in ['no','n']:
        print("Alien!")
        break
    else:
        print("Cool")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a side note:  Here you can see a great case for using a **for loop** since there is code that is repeated many times.  Personally, I would do the following to solve this problem.

1. Create a list of questions
2. Iterate through the list of questions
3. If any answer is no, break and print Alien.

Now for the code:

```
# Initialize our list
lst = ["Are you human? ", "Are you living on planet Earth? ","Do you live on 
land? ","Have you eaten in the last year? ","Is 2 + 2 = 4? "]

#Create a flag for Alien
flag = False

#Iterate through the list
for question in lst: 
  answer = input(question)
  if answer == 'no':

    #Print alien
    print('Alien')

    #Change Flag
    flag = True

    #Break out of the loop
    break
#Check to see if our flag was thrown during the loop
if flag == False:
  print('cool')
```

If you want more help on solving coding challenges like this one, check out this intro to python course: https://exlskills.com/learn-en/courses/learn-python-essentials-for-data-science-intro_to_python/content